# Using internal log and manage exceptions

Tags: c#, nlog

I've two problem using Nlog internal logging.
Firstly while starting I execute the following code:

```
LogManager.Configuration = new
NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration("NLog.debug.config", true);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
InternalLogger.LogToConsoleError = true;
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppPath, "Nlog.log");
```

My first problem is the logToconsole do not display in my Visual output. Is that normal ?

My second issue is when I try to log on C:\log.txt (to test internal log)
This should crash because Nlog cannot create files at the root of C:.
Unfortunaly It do not crash (and do not create the file) (it works with C:\test\log.txt for example).

Here my internal Nlog.log content:

> 2015-04-23 18:44:09.8593 Debug TestManager.Info Rejecting message
>   because of a filter. 2015-04-23 18:44:09.8593 Debug TestManager.Info
>   Rejecting message because of a filter. 2015-04-23 18:44:09.8593 Debug
>   TestManager.Info Rejecting message because of a filter. 2015-04-23
>   18:44:09.8593 Debug TestManager.Info Rejecting message because of a
>   filter. 2015-04-23 18:44:09.8593 Trace Opening C:test.log with
>   concurrentWrite=False

Rejected is normal (I've several targets)

So Why haven't I exception and no trace ?

Thanks a lot for the incoming help

Answer (score 0):

NLog probably uses the conventional `Console.WriteLine(…)` method to send messages to console. It will not work in WinForms application because `Console.WriteLine(…)` does nothing in WinForms application by default. It only works, however, when you are debugging from Visual Studio since that provides a console window for `Output`

Try to call Win32 API function `AllocConsole` at the beginning of your application. It should create a console for your WinForms application and enable `Console.WriteLine(…)` function. Here you can find an example of the code that shows how to call `AllocConsole`. ["See link for setting this up"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/b7a14400-6d72-4fbf-9927-0966f69ef4a2/).

Also quoting Nlog github page on internal logging

> There are 3 environment variables which control internal logging. You
>   can set those variables before running your program to enable internal
>   logging:
>
> NLOG_INTERNAL_LOG_TO_CONSOLE - if this variable is found in the
>   environment, will outputs internal diagnostic information to the
>   console

For your second question, looking at your logs I believe you did not provide the path  in correct format by escaping the backslash character
It should be like

```
fileName="C:\\logssamplefile.txt"
```

Please note that this worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
I've tested AllocConsole and even with all 

InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
InternalLogger.LogToConsoleError = true;
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;

It won't log on console (or visual output) . 

Concerning the filename I set it programmatically and path is valid (that's why its intended to crash because I Nlog cannot create new file at C:\ root)

I'm stuck with this behavior because I need to manage Nlog error ...

Comment: If you want to see the NLog output in the debugger, use the DebuggerTarget or the OutputDebugStringTarget.  ConsoleTarget is ok if you already have a console window, or if you want to create a console window so you can see the NLog output as your program runs.

Comment: I currently send de to my output my logs via xsi:type="Debugger" but xsi:type="OutputDebugString" do not work for me

I do not really understand how internallogging and exception raising works for Nlog. Eeven if I activate all I Can nothing happens. no exception is raised even if I'm sure there is an error (no log written)